# calendar activity with function finish()

Tags: android, date, android-activity, calendar, simpledateformat

In my application I have an activity that contains the calendar. When I select a date, I need to stay in memory and go back to the previous activity. If I use the finish () function it does not make me scroll the calendar and immediately returns to the main activity. Why?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Date x = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); //currentDate
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String format = df.format(x);
            i1 = i1 + 1;

            data = new Data(i2,i1,i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Calendar Activity start with i use this button

```
 setData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this,CalendarActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try using `setOnDateSetListener()` rather than `OnDateChangeListener()`.

Comment: please share how you started this calendar activity